# twitter search Api connect timeout

Tags: java, api, search, twitter, timeout

I am running this program to search for tweets. Getting the below exception pasted.

Could any one help me what the problem is?

please let me know if any other details required.

Thanks

```
    public class KrishsSearchTweets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                //  My Applications Consumer and Auth Access Token
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer("key", "secret");
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("token", "secret"));

                System.out.println("Search Program started");
                Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j");
                query.setSince("20120101");
                Object result = twitter.search(query);
                System.out.println("Search Program ended");


        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Search Program started
connect timed out
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=12c94143
    TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-12c94143 43208640-465ee2e3], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
        at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1835)
        at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:282)
        at KrishsSearchTweets.main(KrishsSearchTweets.java:30)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:156)
    Failed to get timeline: connect timed out
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem got resolved. Its because of firewall in the network which didn't allow for connection and timed out.

After i removed the firewall it worked.